# motivation of definition of semigroup

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis

I knew the definition of a group and semigroup. However, I do not see the point why we need the definition of semigroups without "good" algebraic properties as groups. Can someone motivate the motivation of semigroup? I always see semigroups in functional analysis books. What is its intuition difference between groups's semigroup and semigroups in functional analysis?

Comment: it's a practical issue. Lots of things are not groups but they are semigroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another motivation is the treatment of time-dependent processes, governed by ordinary or partial differential equations.

Let $x(t)$ denote the value of the process at time $t$. If the value of the process for any time $t'>t$ depends solely on $t$ and $t'-t$ but not on the history before $t$, then the mapping $S$ from initial value to value of the process at time $t$ is often a semi-group:
$$
x(t') = S(t'-t)x(t) 
$$
with 
$$
S(t_1 + t_2) = S(t_1) S(t_2)
$$
and associativity. Here, the set $\{S(t), t \in \mathbb R\}$ with concatenation is the semigroup.

The prime example being the ODE
$$
x'(t) = Ax(t), \ x(0)=x_0
$$
with semigroup $S(t) = e^{At}$.
In this case, $\{S(t)\}_{t\in\mathbb R}$ is even a group.

In the case of parabolic pde, i.e. heat equation, the process is not reversable, and $\{S(t)\}_{t\in \mathbb R}$ is only a semigroup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about functional analysis more broadly, but in $C^*$-algebras, there are plenty of examples where (abelian) semigroups appear more naturally. Namely, $K_0$ and the Cuntz semigroup are defined first as semigroups. Hopefully these examples extrapolate to more general situations:

In the case of $K_0$, for reasons that you mention, it's easier to deal with a group so you can take the Grothendieck group of the semigroup. But it's still useful in many cases to keep track of the initial semigroup since this can create a partial order structure, making $K_0$ a partially ordered abelian group. To take an example, you can take the semigroup $\mathbb{N}$ and form the group $\mathbb{Z}$, but in addition to being a group, $\mathbb{Z}$ is an ordered group with positive elements being the positive integers. So semigroups are useful because they can add more structure.

In the case of the Cuntz semigroup, the semigroups often include infinite elements, which makes taking the Grothendieck group result in a trivial group. For example, if we take the semigroup $S=\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}$, then the fact that $\infty + n = \infty$ means that if we add an inverse for $\infty$, we get $n = 0$ for all $n$. So to keep the information, we can't form a group.

Answer (score 1):

Take your every day finite ring $\mathbb Z_n$. $(\mathbb Z_n,+)$ is a group of course; but what should we call $(\mathbb Z_n, \cdot)$? Multiplication may not be a group, but we can certainly make some general assertions about it that are useful.

Answer (score 1):

The natural numbers with respect to addition, perhaps the most familiar number system of all, give an immediate example of a semigroup that isn't a group.  If we include zero in the natural numbers, then we have a monoid (i.e., there's an identity element.)  In light of this example, I'd say that semigroups are actually more natural (pun kind intended) than groups. :)